# How to select combination of 4 digits number from table columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table as below:-

```
id | columnA | columnB | columnC
1    7234        3432    3245
2    1237        1123    6546
3    4421        9371    7324
4    1244        1424    4237
```

How can I select combination records when I pass in "2374" in my select statement?

My expected result should be

```
id | columnA | columnB | columnC
1    7234        3432    3245
3    4421        9371    7324
4    1244        1424    4237
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Can some of the digits be the same?

Comment: Hi @Nick, sorry for late reply. Yes, digits can be same such as 1123, 4144, or even 8888. My mysql version is 5.6.44

Comment: In that case I think you're probably going to need to go with something like @danblack solution and do the final filtering in your application.

Comment: alrite...thx nick

Comment: Would `7777` match?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, if keyword is 7777 and column value got 7777, then should list in output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to read, but it works:

```
set @s = '2374';
select * from tablename
where id in (
  select distinct t1.id
  from (
    select t.id, t.abc, group_concat(t.d order by t.d separator '') col
    from (
      select id, abc, substring(col, n, 1) d
      from (
        select id, 'A' abc, columnA col from tablename union all
        select id, 'B', columnB from tablename union all
        select id, 'C', columnC from tablename
      ) t cross join (
        select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4  
      ) v  
    ) t  
    group by t.id, t.abc
  ) t1 inner join (
    select group_concat(t.d order by t.d separator '') s
    from (
      select substring(@s, 1, 1) d union all select substring(@s, 2, 1) union all 
      select substring(@s, 3, 1) union all select substring(@s, 4, 1) 
    ) t
  ) t2 on t2.s = t1.col 
)
```

What this code does is: 
sorts the digits inside the column's value, so `4237` becomes `2347` and compares against the (also) sorted sorted `2374`--> `2347`.
For this sorting I used `group_concat()`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tEypmySLHEMYTvUmjmQM7u/1).
Results:

```
| id  | columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1   | 7234    | 3432    | 3245    |
| 3   | 4421    | 9371    | 7324    |
| 4   | 1244    | 1424    | 4237    |
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to consider a string of number as some sort of set is to use a regular expression. Using "2374" as the string you change this to the regular expression:

```
[2374]{4}
```

The number in `[]` are the character set, and `{4}` means match 4 characters that match this.

Note this will also match `4444` which may not be desired.

Then you'll need to match this for every column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(columnA, '[2374]{4}') OR
 REGEXP_LIKE(columnB, '[2374]{4}') OR
 REGEXP_LIKE(columnC, '[2374]{4}')
```

Its really not a sane thing to try to do in SQL. Programming languages are better at this.

Comment: The last line should be the first line

Comment: @danblack, I tried your idea in my case but it does not work ( I using mysql 5.6.44 version). I tried to apply REGEXP to replace REGEXP_LIKE. but the result is not correct.

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE got added in MySQL-8.0

Comment: Hi @danblack, is there any alternative solution for this case ? I am using version 5.6.44. :(

Comment: Yes! There's other answers here. Their complexity should indicate that the problem you are solving isn't suited to SQL. You can't get modern features on older mysql major versions. What's stopping you from upgrading? Or do you want to keep working around hard problems with tools that aren't suited to that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to match all four characters, you can use `LIKE` four times:

```
where cola like '%2%' and
      cola like '%3%' and
      cola like '%4%' and
      cola like '%7%'
```

You would then repeat this for each column:

```
where (cola like '%2%' and
       cola like '%3%' and
       cola like '%4%' and
       cola like '%7%'
      ) or
      (colb like '%2%' and
       colb like '%3%' and
       colb like '%4%' and
       colb like '%7%'
      ) or
      (colc like '%2%' and
       colc like '%3%' and
       colc like '%4%' and
       colc like '%7%'
      )
```

This does not handle duplicates.  For that, pre-process the inputs and phrase it like this:

```
where cola like '%1%1%' and
      cola like '%2%' and
      cola like '%3%'
```

So the complete solution would look like:

```
where (cola like '%1%1%' and
       cola like '%2%' and
       cola like '%3%'
      ) or
      (colb like '%1%1%' and
       colb like '%2%' and
       colb like '%3%'
      ) or
      (colc like '%1%1%' and
       colc like '%2%' and
       colc like '%3%'
      )
```

If the digits are independent, I would question why they are being stored in a single value.  That seems like a data modeling problem.

That said, if you do store them in a single value, then you should store them in a *canonical* form, such as increasing values:  always `'2347'` never '`'7432'` or any other ordering.

If you do this, your comparisons will be much simpler.

Comment: Hi Gordon, your solution is simple. But it does not match with the exact result. For example, if I pass in 2,3,4,7, all results with 2,3,4,7 will be appear. What I want is only record with exact 2,3,4,and 7 combination only.

Comment: @Eddy . . . I am missing your point.  There are four characters being compared.  If all four are 2, 3, 4, and 7, then that is all of them.  A complete match regardless of order.

Comment: I tried your solution but no luck. I stuck over here few days and no idea how to do. Can u provide some sample code for this case?